# Contradiction with inequality of complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Prove that if $\vert a \vert \neq R$,then $$\int_{\vert z\vert =R} \frac{\vert dz\vert}{\vert z-a\vert \vert z+a\vert}<\frac{2\pi R}{\vert R^2-\vert a\vert ^2\vert}...(1)$$

Proof:

We have the following result $\int_J \vert dz\vert=\int_a^b\vert J'(t)\vert dt=l(J)$ which is the length of $J$.

Then $\int_{\vert z\vert =R} \frac{\vert dz\vert}{\vert z-a\vert \vert z+a\vert}=\frac{1}{{\vert z-a\vert \vert z+a\vert}} \int _{\vert z\vert =R} \vert dz\vert=2\pi R\frac{1}{{\vert z-a\vert \vert z+a\vert}}$.

But $\frac{1}{{\vert z-a\vert \vert z+a\vert}}=\frac{1}{\vert R^2-\vert a^2\vert \vert}$.

Therefore $(1)$ would be an equality, where is my mistake?

Comment: You cannot bring the terms in $z$ outside the integral

Comment: But it's a constant. isn't it? @Ant

Comment: @AnneliseToft:it isn't. $(z-a)(z+a)$ depends on $z$.

Comment: but you're missing the absolute value @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @AnneliseToft: that's irrelevant. If $(z-a)(z+a)$ depends on $z$, the absolute value of $(z-a)(z+a)$ depends on $z$ too, so you cannot bring it out of the integral.

Comment: But I think $\vert z\vert =\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ is a real number. Can't it be applied to my problem? @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @AnneliseToft: still irrelevant. $$\int_{0}^{a}f(z)\,dz \neq f(z) \int_{0}^{a} 1\,dz$$ also because the RHS depends on $z$ while the LHS does not.

Comment: well in your example of course we can't bring outside $f(z)$. I just thought I could do it in my exercise. @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please be aware then when you write something like
$$ \int_{0}^{a}f(z)\,dz = f(z)\int_{0}^{a} 1\,dz $$
a sweet kitten dies. To avoid a massacre, it is enough to notice that
$$ \left|\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{z^2-a^2}\right| \leq \oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{\left|z^2-a^2\right|} $$
by the triangle inequality, and by the triangle inequality $\left|z^2-a^2\right|\geq |z^2|-|a^2|$, hence:
$$ \left|\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{z^2-a^2}\right| \leq \oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{\left|z^2\right|-\left|a^2\right|} = \oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{R^2-\left|a^2\right|}=\frac{2\pi R}{R^2-|a|^2}.$$

Comment: a sweet kitten dies...Thanks to you I think I won't kill more kittens anymore.